# Show that $E\setminus S^1\times\{0\}$ is connected

Tags: general-topology

Show that $E\setminus S^1\times\{0\}$ is connected, where $E=\{(z,w)\mid w^2=c^2z, \text{for some } c\in\mathbb{R}\}\subset S^1\times\mathbb{C}$.

I am trying to show that $E\setminus S^1\times\{0\}$ is path connected and hence connected, where the path connectedness can be observed if one tries to draw this space. I am having trouble in finding a function $f:[0,1]\to E\setminus S^1\times\{0\}$, such that $f(0)=x$ and $f(1)=y$, where $x,y\in E\setminus S^1\times\{0\}$, the basic definition of a path connected space. I have a wild guess if the path connecting any two points can be given by $\gamma(t)=(w-1)e^{2\pi it}$, $t\in [0,1]$. Is this correct?

Anyway, kindly help me to show that $E\setminus S^1\times\{0\}$ is connected by either using path connectedness or by some other way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One may observe that
$$E \setminus S^1 \times \{0\} = \{(f(w),w) \mid w \in \mathbb C - \{0\}\}
$$
where $f : \mathbb C - \{0\} \to S^1$ is defined by
$$f(w) = \left( \frac{w}{|w|} \right)^2
$$
The point here is that for any $z \in S^1$ and $w \in \mathbb C - \{0\}$ we have

$z=f(w) \iff w^2 = |w|^2 z \iff$ there exists $c \in \mathbb R - \{0\}$ such that $w^2 = c^2 z$  $\iff$  $(z,w) \in E \setminus S^1 \times \{0\}$.

This shows that $E \setminus S^1 \times \{0\}$ is the graph of a continuous function. Therefore, like the graph of any continuous function, $E \setminus S^1 \times \{0\}$ is homeomorphic to its domain which in this case is $\mathbb C - \{0\}$. Since $\mathbb C - \{0\}$ is (path) connected, and since (path) connectedness is a homeomorphism invariant, it follows that $E \setminus S^1 \times \{0\}$ is (path) connected.